# Google Maps, Bing Maps, OpenStreetMaps and MapQuest limitation

Tags: api, google-maps, bing-maps, openstreetmap

I'm very confused reading the online term of use of some Online Map Service (like Google Maps, Bing Maps, OpenStreetMaps and Mapquest)...

There is a way to use Google or Bing Maps on a website for non-commercial or commercial pourpose without any daily limitation of request?? What kind of Api I can use for free without any limitation of use or request, if I want to see a map on my site with several point of interest inserted by me??

I have read that in free version of Google or Bing some ads may appear sometimes inside the maps, and I cannot insert in my webpages any ads from another provider different from Google or Bing. It's true?

If I want to use OpenStreetMaps (an opensource Maps Database) or the partner MapQuest, it's true that there aren't any limitations of daily request or appearing ads on the maps or policy of exclusive banner campaign??

But, at the end, If I try to build a portal with this maps, and I want to plan in the future the insertion of some ads and the creation of a little company, I'm doing a commercial or not-commercial use (now and in future)??

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. What *specific* parts of the Terms of Service of those map providers aren't clear to you? The questions seem awfully vague (IIRC, Google Maps has *this exact question* spelled out for you in their FAQ: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/faq.html#hightrafficsite )

Answer (score 9):

Google [recently announced new advertising and rate limiting in their terms of service](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/04/updates-to-google-maps-apigoogle-earth.html). Websites will be forced to display ads in their maps, or pay for a premium account. Popular websites (resulting in lots of hits of google map tile server) will also need to pay for a premium account. It's not clear if your intended use will trigger those limits.

OpenStreetMap might offer a viable alternative. They do run a map tile server which can be used to embed a slippy map on your website. There is also an open source javascript library called OpenLayers (among other options), meaning that you can be free of google and their ads. OpenStreetMap do however operate a strict [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy) to protect the service which is paid for by donations, and run by volunteers.

OpenStreetMap also *uniquely* offers another approach: [Create your own tile server](http://weait.com/content/build-your-own-openstreetmap-server), rendering the raw map data yourself. This might be a sensible option if you run a very popular website, or if you require only a limited area of the world to be shown. It's also really neat because you have full control over rendering style. It's a fairly technical process though ...but

Because this is possible, a number of third parties will offer you a map tile service built using OpenStreetMap data. e.g. [MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map), [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/), [TileServer](http://www.tileserver.com/),  [TileDrawer](http://tiledrawer.com/), or [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/)